# Angular ng-message is not shown up when adding a ng-pattern

Tags: javascript, validation, angular-material

I added ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{1,7}$/" to my input field (type=number) to validate the numbers without 'e' letter.I am using angular material.It is validating and showing the red color in the input but the validation message is not showing up.It only shown for this kind of similar value '3223233e3'

This is what happens when I supply a number and a single `e`:

[image: Validation happen when enter this number and e]

This is what happens when I supply many `e`'s:

[image: Validation not happen when enter e]

```html
<input type="number" id="txtAnd" ng-model="txtAnd" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{1,25}$/" name="AndOcc" required />
<div ng-messages="Three.AndOcc.$error">
  <div ng-message="required">Please supply a value</div>
  <div ng-message="pattern">Please supply a valid value</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post a snippet of your code so that others can help you.

Comment: I have updated the description.Added the screen shots of code and the error

Comment: Maybe because you didn't put `ngMessages` in your app.js? Or maybe because you didn't import `ngMessages` in the first place? Or maybe because you didn't wrap it in a `<form name="Three">`?

Comment: Everything is imported.Validation is also happening.But the issue is the validation message is not showing .Only the input item is becoming red as in the second image.

Comment: Here is a working [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Chan4077/pen/NpZqxw)

Comment: In that codepen please try with entering 'e' and check whether the validation is showing in the bottom. No actually,only the input item is changing to red .I need to get the error message as well

Answer (score 0):

In the pen by @Edric,

try this code

`<div ng-messages="Three.AndOcc.$error">
    <div ng-message="required">Please supply a value</div>
    <div ng-message="number">Please supply a valid value</div>
</div>`